# div has a 100% width when page is full size but reduced the width when page size is reduced

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image, it has a width of 100% when page is full size. Like this:

[image]

When the page is re-sized, the width reduced. Like this:

[image]

**My HTML:**

```
<section>
  <div class="links">
    <div class="links_area">
      <ul id="menu">
        //html goes here      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**My CSS:**

```
div {
display: block;
}
section { clear:both;display: block;}
.links{background:url(../images/links_bg.gif) repeat-x; width:100%; height:37px;}
.links_area{width:1003px; height:37px; margin:0 auto; }
ul#menu {  float: right;  height:auto;  margin: 0 0; width: 796px;}
ul#menu li {display:inline;}
ul#menu li a {display:block; float:left; background-position:0 0; color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:13px; padding:12px 10px 10px 4px; border-right:none;}
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle so we can play with it?

Answer (score 3):

This rule:

```
.links_area{width:1003px; height:37px; margin:0 auto; }
```

gives that div a fixed width, but since the next rule floats the `#menu`,

```
ul#menu {  float: right;  height:auto;  margin: 0 0; width: 796px;}
```

the div does **not** contain it, so it (`#menu`) resizes when the window resizes. Try adding `overflow:auto;` to the `.links_area` rule.

Answer (score 2):

After Your UL put one div Like 
`<div style="clear:both; float:none"></div>.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide `100%` width in `.links_area` instead of `width:1003px`.

Try this :

```
.links_area{width:100%;}
```